# How to list all user session paramters in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, session

How do I list all user session parameters in Oracle Database?

I found that Oracle provides **SYS_CONTEXT** function ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm)) allowing to retrieve chosen parameter in a following manner:

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'NLS_CURRENCY') FROM DUAL;
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') FROM DUAL;
...
```

This is not ideal as I would like to retrieve all parameters without naming them individually, as it is possible to do with nls_session_parameters ([link](https://ferhatsengonul.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/to-show-nls-parameters-for-session-database-instance-together-by-pivot-and-listagg-on-11gr2/)):

```
SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters;
```

So back to my original question - **How can I list ALL user session parameters?**

Are there any tables/viewes where all parameters can be retrieved in a smarter way? From my research what I found was rather cumbersome methods, like [this one](http://www.oracle-wiki.net/startsqllistsessiondetails).

Comment: Any answer to your quest. I have the same quest.

Answer (score 4):

You can use NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS, NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS and NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS (in priority order).

Higher priority settings override lower priority settings :
[Setting NLS Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch3globenv.htm)

Comment: The question is about [`USERENV` parameters for `sys_context()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions199.htm#SQLRF06117), not NLS parameters. Only a few values overlap between the two.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT * FROM V$PARAMETER; it includes NLS parameters as well